# Get each value of each attribute with its frequency from a list of POJOs

Tags: java, collections, java-8, functional-programming

I have a POJO like this:

```
class Employee {

    String name;
    String designation;
    String address;

    //Getters and setters
    //All args constructor

}
```

And I have populated a list of such objects.

Now, I need to get each value of each attribute with its frequency.

For example, if my list is like this:

```
List<Employee> list = List.of(

    new Employee("Amit", "Manager", "Delhi"),
    new Employee("Arun", "VP", "Agra"),
    new Employee("Arun", "President", "Bangalore"),
    new Employee("Rahul", "VP", "Delhi"),
    new Employee("Amit", "Manager", "Agra")

);
```

Then I should get something like this (note that for each attribute, its values are mapped to its frequecies):

```
{
    name = {Rahul = 1, Arun = 2, Amit = 2},
    designation = {President = 1, VP = 2, Manager = 2},
    address = {Delhi = 2, Bangalore = 1, Agra = 2}
}
```

The statement given below works fine for the current data (where it is guaranteed that no attribute of any object in the list would contain a null value):

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> attributeFrequencies = list.stream()
    .flatMap(e -> Map.of(
                "name", e.getName(),
                "designation", e.getDesignation(),
                "address", e.getAddress()
              ).entrySet().stream())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getKey,
                            Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue, Collectors.counting())));
```

However, if I change my original list to something like this:

```
List<Employee> list = List.of(

    new Employee("Amit", "Manager", "Delhi"),
    new Employee("Arun", "VP", null),
    new Employee("Arun", "President", "Bangalore"),
    new Employee("Rahul", "VP", "Delhi"),
    new Employee("Amit", "Manager", null)

);
```

Here one (or more) attribute(s) has (have) null value(s), then the Java statement which worked earlier, now gives NullPointerException.

My use case is such that I want to have the frequencies of nulls as well in each attribute, so I don't want to filter out the objects containing null values from the list.

Please suggest some elegant, Java 8 based solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the value null with String "null" everywhere to vanquish the NullPointerException, and then then following seems to work perfectly fine:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Long>> attributeFrequencies =

    List.stream().flatMap(e -> {
        Map<String, String> hm = new HashMap<>();
        hm.put("name", e.getName());
        hm.put("designation", e.getDesignation());
        hm.put("address", e.getAddress());
        return hm.entrySet().stream().map(entry -> {
            if(entry.getValue() == null) {
                entry.setValue(null);   
            }
            return entry;
            });
        }).collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                    Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Collectors.groupingBy(
                        Map.Entry::getValue,
                        Collectors.counting())));
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple method with a ternary statement like so ->

```
static String defaultIfNotNull(String defaultValue, String toReturnIfNull) {
    return defaultValue == null ? toReturnIfNull : defaultValue;
}
```

I believe this does not require to be explained.

And I applied this to your `Map.of` parameters here ->

```
.flatMap(e -> 
    Map.of(
            "name", defaultIfNotNull(e.getName(), "null"),
            "designation", defaultIfNotNull(e.getDesignation(), "null"),
            "address", defaultIfNotNull(e.getAddress(), "null"))
        .entrySet().stream())
```

While this may not be the best way to do it, it is a quick fix and should allow you to solve the issue.